# Change of variable to find the area of $\iint_T (x+y)^3\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This is an example from my textbook, we're attempting to find the area of $\iint_T (x+y)^3\,dx\,dy$ where $T$ is a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(2,0)$. We use the transformation $u=y-x$ and $v=x+y$, trivially $dx\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\,du\,dv$ but I'm confused as to how they're obtaining these lines in the following diagram:

[image]

The original triangle in $T$ has the lines $y=x$, $y=2-x$ and $y=0$ but the only equation I can find using the new variables is $v=2$, I'm not sure where the other lines are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

From the substitution:
$$
u=y-x \qquad v=x+y
$$
we have:
$$
x=\frac{v-u}{2} \qquad y=\frac{v+u}{2}
$$

If you substitute in the equations of the sides of the original triangle, you find the sides of the new triangle.